# How to format pandas data frame using style.format method to round upto 2 decimal places?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe called fb_df and it has a daily_return column which I want to round off up to 2decimal places with a % sign at the end(e.g. 1.05%).

I have tried multiple options by looking at official docs and other references but it is not working and actually showing no changes in output and at the same time it shows no error while running the cell.

```
fb_df.style.format({'daily_return':"{:,.0f}%"})
```

[This is an output of an above code, you can see daily_return column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tZ8J.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
fb_df.style.format({'daily_return': '{:.2f}%'})
```

or

```
fb_df.style.format('{:.2f} %', subset='daily_return')
```

See the `Notes` section in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).

(in your screenshot, there seems to be no underline between `daily` and `return`)

Comment: thanks for answering, but it is still not working,

Comment: are you sure your column name is `daily_return` (with underline)?

Comment: No, I saw my mistake there, even after keeping 'daily return' there are no changes  in output

Comment: what is the output of `fb_df['daily return'].info()`?

Comment: Do you want to know dtype of values in that column? then it is float64

FYI for the above code line, I'm getting attribute error as fd_df['daily return'] is a series. hence it has no such method info()

Comment: maybe you should update your pandas (Series.info() was introduced in 1.4.0) and maybe it'll work then?